# How do I add a property to an array type?

Tags: typescript

In Vue, we have this type:

```
Vue.$refs: {
    [key: string]: Vue | Element | Vue[] | Element[];
}
```

I have a third-party library (vuelidate) that adds a `$v` property to everything Vue. It does not define types, so I'm doing it myself.

```
declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    $v: any
  }

  interface Element {
    $v: any
  }
}
```

---

When I try to use `$v` on $refs like so, typescript complains:

```
this.$refs.form.$v
```

Results in

```
Property '$v' does not exist on type 'Vue[]'.
```

That makes sense to me. What doesn't make sense, though, is how to add a property to `Vue[]` and `Element[]` so that this code compiles.

---

I've poured over the documentation, Stack Overflow, you name it, and I can't find a solution to this. How do I add a type to a specific array?

I understand why this doesn't work:

```
interface Vue[] {
  $v: any
}
```

But I have no idea what to do to fix it.

Comment: Arrays have to be accessed with numeric keys; you will have to use, for example, `this.$refs.form[0].$v`

Comment: @ExplosionPills That's a good thought, but the union type is `Vue | Element | Vue[] | Element[]`, which means some of the potential types don't have index signatures.

Comment: In that case I think you will have to cast to the type you need at the time

Comment: Yes, I also guess you will have to use `(this.$refs.form as Vue).$v`

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I was definitely overthinking the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting works, but I appreciate your desire to declare types so you don't have to cast every time.  `Vue[]` is actually shorthand for `Array<Vue>`, a parameterization of the built-in generic interface `Array`.  You can add properties to `Array`, but then they will be declared on arrays of all types, not just `Vue[]`.  You can mitigate this a bit with a conditional type, like so:

```
// Wrap with `declare global { ... }` if the file is an ES6 module
interface Array<T> {
    $v: T extends Vue | Element ? any : unknown;
}
```

But truly, you don't want `$v` on every `Vue[]`, but only on `Vue.$refs`.  Unfortunately, given the way `Vue.$refs` is declared, I don't believe there's any way to make this change via augmentation.  You'd have to add a modified version of the `vue` package to your project and change the declaration to read:

```
export interface Vue {
  // ...
  readonly $refs: { [key: string]: (Vue | Element | Vue[] | Element[]) & {$v: any} };
  // ...
}
```

Obviously, this change would not be appropriate to send upstream.  But you could send a PR to add a hook that other packages such as `vuelidate` would then be able to augment:

```
// In vue/types/vue.d.ts:
export interface RefExtra {}
export interface Vue {
  // ...
  readonly $refs: { [key: string]: (Vue | Element | Vue[] | Element[]) & RefExtra };
  // ...
}

// In vuelidate typings (or your project for now):
declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface RefExtra {
    $v: any
  }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic answer, thank you. Everything I wanted to know about how it should have been working.